# How to deploy AAR in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, apache-axis, war

I have file in AAR format generated using Ant but I would like to deploy it in Tomcat server. Tomcat support only WAR files. I tried to generate war file using command `jar cvf smth.war` but it doesnt work without manifest.
Anybody know how to convert AAR to WAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put .aar files into the WEB-INF/services folder of an Axis2.war file, then you can deploy the Axis2.war file to tomcat.

The layout of an axis2.war file is given [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html#services).

Comment: Where is this Axis2.war file?