# How to deploy an .aar file in Tomcat server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, deployment, apache-axis

I am trying to build a sample apache axis 2 project in tomcat server. In most of them, in the readme file, it is said to deploy StockQuoteService.aar.

```
"Type "ant generate.service" from Axis2_HOME/samples/quickstartxmlbeans
directory. Then deploy the 
AXIS2_HOME/samples/quickstartxmlbeans/build/service/build/lib/StockQuoteService.aar "
```

How to do this deploying thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how convert \*.aar to \*.war (web services)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531370/how-convert-aar-to-war-web-services)

Comment: The given answer is not clear and that is why I am asking this.(and it is 3 years old and so commenting to that answer may not have replies) And u can see the 2 questions are different. May be the answer is similar for someone who knows the answer.

Comment: @Thilo - If u can please answer this.

Comment: I think the answer still stands: You take that aar file and stick it into the Axis2 web application.

Comment: I am trying to run sample projects in axis2. So where are the WEB-INF/services  axis2.war file ?

Answer (score 4):

For a simple, ad hoc deployment, you can do this:

1. Download the axis2 WAR distribution. It comes as a ZIP file.
2. Extract the file "axis2.war" from the ZIP.
3. Copy axis2.war into Tomcat's `webapps` folder. Tomcat unpack axis2.war into a folder named `axis2`, which will contain a folder named `services`.
4. Copy your AAR files into the `services` folder. Axis2 will autodeploy them the same way Tomcat autodeploys WARs placed into its `webapps` folder.

Access your service as [http://example.com:8080/axis2/services/*servicename*](http://example.com:8080/axis2/services/_servicename_).

Comment: Any way I deployed the axis2.war file using tomcat manager (web page). After deploying it, that axis2 folder was created.